# Explanation of ruby laser behaviour

Tags: visible-light, laser

One of the reason why He-Ne (*Helium Neon laser*) is better than *Ruby Laser* is that, He-Ne laser produces light as a continuous beam unlike Ruby laser which produces light in *short pulses*. But why is that so? Why does ruby laser behave in this way? Can anybody please explain in somewhat detail manner?

Comment: Because ruby is a three-level laser, so can not sustain a steady-state population inversion.

Comment: A [CW ruby laser](https://www.osapublishing.org/osac/abstract.cfm?uri=osac-2-1-184) is possible.

Comment: HeNe laser is also not better than a ruby laser. What is better?